# Windows Virtual Store location in other locales

Tags: windows, localization, locale, uac

How can you get the windows virtual store path in any locale? For English, we can hardcode it as `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`, but from what I can tell, "VirtualStore" is a localized string which is different in different languages. Is there *any* way at all I can get the localized path to the virtual store?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to retrieve the path to the `VirtualStore` folder.

The UAC Data Redirection feature is a **temporary** compatibility hack; used only to make buggy applications not crash. Microsoft says you should not rely on it. Any applications for Windows 2000 or later should not need the VirtualStore.

Fortunately, your application doesn't even need to **care** about the path to the virtual store folder.

## Disable Data Redirection for your app

You can turn off Data Redirection entirely (so that nothing ever goes into the VirtualStore), by adding a **requestedExecutionLevel** of **asInvoker** to your application's assembly manifest:

**AssemblyManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Or you can simply continue to read and write files from the place where you shouldn't. Data Redirection will transparently let you see files that are in the VirtualStore folder.

The best solution is to disable file virtualization, and fix your app.

Microsoft isn't inclined to add features for a temporary hack to let buggy apps limp along. As such, there's no documented way to the path.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately, the old application has put data in the virtual store that the new application's installer **must** locate.

Comment: @PhilipG.Lee i would crawl the entire `AppDataLocal` tree, looking for your application's folder name as one of the folder names.

Comment: Thanks @ian That's precisely what I did :)